# Is there a generic way to populate various generic collections via reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

For example here's some code to create a `List<int>` via reflection (yes, I know there are functions to convert from array to list, the question is not about that solution the question is about using reflection without knowing the types in advance.

```
public static T Convert<T>(int[] src)
{
    Type genericClassType = typeof(T);
    Type[] typeParameters = genericClassType.GetGenericArguments();
    Type genericTypeDef = genericClassType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    Type constructedClass = genericTypeDef.MakeGenericType(typeParameters);
    T arrayLike = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass);

    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = arrayLike.GetType().GetMethod("Add", typeParameters);

    foreach (int value in src) {
        method.Invoke(arrayLike, new []{(object)value});
    }

    return arrayLike;
}
```

So I can call it like this

```
int[] src = {4, 5, 6};
List<int> copy = Convert<List<int>>(src);
```

But I'd also like to be able to call it like this

```
int[] src = {4, 5, 6};
Stack<int> copy = Convert<Stack<int>>(src);

int[] src = {4, 5, 6};
Queue<int> copy = Convert<Queue<int>>(src);
```

But I can't because for example `Stack` has no `Add` method

Effectively I'm doing some deserialization work and trying to make it generic or semi generic. The source data has no type info. It's just an array of ints but when calling the deserialization code I know what type I want it to be `List`, `Stack`, `Queue` etc...  So, is it possible to generically convert to the given type or would I have to go about writing custom code for every type of generic?

I'm sure at some level `List`, `Stack`, `Queue` are different but C/C++/Assembly programmer in me sees that given an int array and the desired type all the info is there to reconstruct given only a generic constructor (already present in the code above).

Comment: Note that `Stack`, `Queue` and `List` all have constructors that take an `IEnumerable<T>` that you could pass the array.

Comment: Do you know type you are deserializing into (like List) at compile time or only at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

For your specific case, if you just change your `Convert` method to pass the `src` as a parameter to the constructor, it will work:

```
public static T Convert<T>(int[] src)
{
    Type genericClassType = typeof(T);
    Type[] typeParameters = genericClassType.GetGenericArguments();
    Type genericTypeDef = genericClassType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    Type constructedClass = genericTypeDef.MakeGenericType(typeParameters);

    T arrayLike = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass, src);

    return arrayLike;
}
```

So you can then use it like this:

```
int[] src = { 4, 5, 6 };
Stack<int> copy = Convert<Stack<int>>(src);
Queue<int> copy2 = Convert<Queue<int>>(src);
List<int> copy3 = Convert<List<int>>(src);
```

So you may want to add some type checking in the constructor to verify that it can accept types of `IEnumerable<int>`.

But you have to be aware of the order. For example, the collections will contain, in order:

`copy`:

```
6, 5, 4
```

`copy2` and `copy3`:

```
4, 5, 6
```

If you want `copy` to contain them in the same order, just reverse the array:

```
Stack<int> copy = Convert<Stack<int>>(src.Reverse().ToArray());
```

---

#### [Try it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1vweRw)

Comment: good answer but I wonder how I can rephrase my question for a more generic answer. I'm actually handling lots of types of collections and contents, although maybe if can always init a generic with an array of T regardless of what T is that might work. Unfortunately knowing that you have to reverse for stack is out. I'll work on rephrasing the question

Comment: Don't rephrase your question after someone has already answered

Comment: @gman I will add another answer to try to address the other issues you bring up, but I'll leave this here for similar questions in the future.

Comment: @gman You only have to reverse for `Stack` if the serialization code outputs the `Stack` info backwards from the way the `IEnumerable` constructor accepts them.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is it possible to generically convert to the given type or would I have to go about writing custom code for every type of generic?

If they all have a constructor that takes an IEnumerable, then give this a shot:

```
public static T Convert<T>(int[] src) where T : new()
{
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), src);
    return (T)obj;
}
```

[Here it is as a Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NrbhB7)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] src = {4, 5, 6};
        List<int> copy = Convert<List<int>>(src);
        Stack<int> copy1 = Convert<Stack<int>>(src);
        Queue<int> copy2 = Convert<Queue<int>>(src);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",copy));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",copy1));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",copy2));    
    }

    public static T Convert<T>(int[] src) where T : new()
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), src);
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Effectively I'm doing some deserialization work and trying to make it generic or semi generic. The source data has no type info. It's just an array of ints but when calling the deserialization code I know what type I want it to be List, Stack, Queue etc... So, is it possible to generically convert to the given type or would I have to go about writing custom code for every type of generic?

So what I understand is that each type may have a different method of adding elements to the collection (and may or may not take an `IEnumerable<T>` as a constructor argument), and you need to specify that at runtime. We can use an `Action` for that:

```
public static T Convert<T, TArray>(IEnumerable<TArray> src, Action<T, TArray> addMethod) where T : new()
{
    var myType = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

    foreach (var element in src)
        addMethod(myType, element);

    return myType;
}
```

So you need to specify the add method, and you would call the code like this:

```
var copy = Convert<Stack<int>, int>(src, (lst, i) => lst.Push(i));
```

In this case, the first element popped off the stack will be `6`. This is the nature of how a `Stack<T>` works. Stacks are LIFO (last-in/first-out). So the elements are pushed onto the stack in the order they are given (4,5,6) and then are popped off in the reverse order (6,5,4). A `Queue` would present them in FIFO order.

This works with odd collection types:

```
public class SomeStrangeCollectionType<T>
{
    private List<T> _myList = new List<T>();
    
    public void Gibberish(T value)
    {
        _myList.Add(value); 
    }
    
    public T[] ToArray()
    {
        return _myList.ToArray();   
    }
}
```

Which you can call `Convert` on:

```
var strange = Convert<SomeStrangeCollectionType<int>, int>(src, (c, i) => c.Gibberish(i));
```

And will return a result:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", strange.ToArray()));
```

```
4,5,6
```

#### [Try it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S0KqB2)